# Can't connect via SSH to a guest OS on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, virtualbox

I installed centos 7 on virtualbox on my local pc. I configured in the vm 2 adapter cards one as a bridge Adapter and the other as host only adapter : 
[image]

[image]

Right now I have 2 network adapters that are configured with a valid ip address :

- enp0s3 : 192.168.1.95/24 (bridged)
- enp0s8 : 192.168.56.102.24 (host-only)

The configuration for enp0s8 :

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s8"
DEVICE="enp0s8"
ONBOOT="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPADDR=192.168.56.102
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

When I ping google it works which means that the first network card is working fine. However, when I'm trying to connect via putty (ssh) to the vm It fails..

Any idea what else I can check ?

Comment: Which address are you using to connect to? Are you trying to connect from the host or some other needing on your Lan?

Comment: I tried to connect to both of them but it failed. I guess that I should be able to connect only to the second ip. I'm trying to connect from the host.

Comment: Why have you set your host-only interface to be your default route (`DEFROUTE="yes"`)?

Comment: Please add the interface definition for enp0s3 to your question. (As text, not a screenshot.). And the result of either `ip route` or `netstat -rn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was disabling the firewalld service.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the host-side interface for the host-only network?

From the VirtualBox GUI: "File" → "Preferences" → "Network" → "Host-only network" → "(+)Add host-only network"

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Comment: I dont have the option "Host only network" in the path you specified. Just nat framework. I'm working on version 5.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep Adapter 1 Option to NAT and set Adapter 2's attached to: option to Bridged Adapter with name parameter set to WIFI adapter if your system is using WIFI connection. After that you can check for ifconfig and get inet of enp08 or something like that and try to create ssh using that.
[image]

[image]